# How to measure $\mathbb{L}^2$ and $L_z $ simultaneously

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, observables

What does an experiment look like, in which both quantities are measured simultanously?

Comment: I suppose that in a Stern-Gerlach experiment you are able to derive both quantities simultaneously. You get the total angular momentum by dividing the number of spots by two and the projection of the angular momentum along the axis from the location of the spot with respect to the center.